# Can scipy.optimize.brute() optimize vector functions?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

Looking through the documentation of [scipy.optimize.brute()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html), it is not clear to me whether it supports vector functions, and if so, how the range is specified for each coordinate.

For example, consider a simple vector function:

```
f=lambda x: np.sum(x)
```

where `x` is a numpy array of length 50. Let's say I want to search over a range where every coordinate in `x` can be one of `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Is this functionality supported? how would I specify the range parameter to get this?

This specific `f` is only for illustrative purposes, my actual function is much more complicated of course.

Comment: yes, it can. you need to provide a list of lists for the range parameter

Comment: @runnerup `sp.optimize.brute(f,ranges=[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3]])` gives an error: `TypeError: slice expected at most 3 arguments, got 4`

Comment: `brute(f,ranges=[slice(0,5),slice(0,5),slice(0,5)], finish=None)`

Comment: @runnerup Thanks, you want to put that into an answer?